# Stored data not getting destroyed

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I have used resource to generate routes.

The route is:

```
Route::resource('/','TodoController');
```

I am trying to delete the todo task that I have stored in my database.

The code of the view is:

```
<form action="{{ route('destroy',['$todo->id']) }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    {{ method_field('delete') }}
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
</form>
```

And, the code of the controller is:

```
public function destroy(Todo $todo)
{
    $todo->Todo::find($id);
    $todo->delete();

    return redirect()->route('index');
}
```

I was not able to delete the stored task on button click. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This code `$todo->Todo::find($id);` makes no sense. It should be `$todo = Todo::find($id);`

Comment: Could you share the output of `php artisan route:list`?

Comment: @Joe It didn't work

Comment: @mdexp Download this [image](https://send.firefox.com/download/3dd3001cc200d3d6/#FFmtQIM7EHacSdAptd-Cyg) to see the route list

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
<form action="{{ route('destroy', '$todo->id') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('DELETE')
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
</form>
```

In your controller method it should be like this,

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $todo = Todo::findOrFail($id);
    $todo->delete();

    return redirect()->route('index');
}
```

Here you have to store result of query in variable and perform some action on it. It is same as `save()` and `update()` method.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Where will the $id var come from?

Comment: Everything is fine now 

Answer (score 0):

Change your route to:

```
Route::resource('todos','TodoController');
```

This way laravel will declare all the routes you need for the TodoController.

In your button tag you need to put 'submit' in the type attribute. And you need to pass the id as a parameter in the route method. Change your form to:

```
<form action="{{ route('destroy', $todo->id) }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('DELETE')
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
</form>
```

Your controller:

```
public function destroy(Todo $todo, $id)
{
    $todo = Todo::findOrFail($id);
    $todo->delete();

    return redirect()->route('index');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your routes aren't getting registered correctly. I would register the todo resource as:

```php
Route::resource('todos', 'TodoController');
```

Then in your form reference the destroy action by its route name:

```php
<form action="{{ route('todos.destroy', ['todo' => $todo->id]) }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('DELETE')
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
</form>
```

Finally in your controller you already have an instance of Todo model, so you don't have to manually call the find method.

```php
public function destroy(Todo $todo)
{
    $todo->delete();
    return redirect()->route('index');
}
```

Comment: I will try it and let you know